# Using preposition for instead from

Tags: prepositions

I want to know more about using preposition *for* in this sentence:

> Say hello to your sister for me.

Why not *from* me instead of *for*?

I looked through some dictionary articles for preposition for and couldn't find something about such a meaning.

Comment: Because it means to do so on my behalf. Some languages employ two totally different words to distinguish two semi-opposing senses of "for" here, with one "for" meaning "coming/bringing from" and the other "for" meaning "going/taking to". Other languages do not do so, or at least not consistently. For example, translating English *for* into Spanish or Portuguese always requires very carefully choosing *por* in the first sense but  *para* in the second.  I'm sending this to our Learners sister site in case they are more used to explaining this curious subtlety to learners than we might be here.

Comment: Most people where I live (UK) would equally happily say 'from' or 'for' and not really think about any 'subtle difference'.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I'd like to find more information about using preposition for - for it.

Comment: I think your confusion comes from the assumption that "for" means "from" in this sentence. In Russian, we would most likely say "от меня", that is "from me". But here "for me" does not mean "(coming) from me", it means "on my behalf".

Comment: See [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for), definition #5.

Comment: While it's less common, I think "from" works equally well. You say "Tell her hello from me." Then he could go to her and say "Hello from Stan!".

Answer (score 1):

It's "say hello *for* me" because you are asking them to say hello to that person *on your behalf*.

Some people may say "hello from me", but it is an error. Why would you need to tell the person you are talking to that the hello is from you? Who else could it be from?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying meaning is completely different, and follows naturally from the core meanings of the prepositions. *For me* means "on my behalf, for my benefit, in place of me". *From me* means "originating from me".

In this particular instance there is little difference in effective meaning, but that is accidental, because of the meanings of the particular words and the social context.

Comment: I agree, but even so, "for me" meaning "on my behalf" is more idiomatic for most speakers.